# How to read multidimensional JSON data in google sheet appscript?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

How can I read this type of json data like I want profession of ID:12311 in google spreadsheet?

```
{
  "user": [
    {
      "id": 12311,
      "name": "Deffy doof",
      "profession": "Photographer"
    },
    {
      "id": 18341,
      "name": "John Smith",
      "profession": "Developer"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution:

Since this is an array of objects you can reference elements using array notation, e.g., to pull "Photographer":

```
data.user[0].profession
```

**Sample:**

[image]

If you only know the unique ID and not the index, you can filter the array first, then get the element.

```
  var array = data.user.filter(function b(e) { return e.id == 12311 });
  console.log(array[0].profession);
```

### References:

[filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Thank you. That was very helpful

Comment: Very much appreciated :)

Comment: Hi @CarlosM here is once again, in array output of filter the ID is becoming float value like `[{ **id=12311.0**, profession=Photographer, name=Deffy doof}]`

How can I overcome this?

Comment: And if I am taking the data with from a function then it gives an error `var userData = getUser(ss);
  var array = userData.user.filter(function b(e) { return e.id == 11281 });` **Error**: TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined